# Get quantity of refunded items in order for each item and calculate the difference between qty and refund qty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom code which displays order items in Woocommerce orders list in admin. Code displays products and its quantities as it follows on the screen bellow.

[image]

[image]

Problem is that when I partially refund the product for example product with quantity 1 is refunded to 0, it still shows the product in the list. What do I need to do is to change quantity based on the qty & refund qty. Example: if product Weider which is 300x in the order will be partially refunded 4 times as you could see the screen bellow, I want to display 296 instead of 300. If it reachs 0 (refund all), it will be gone from the list.

[image]

I tried this but in **test field** I always get -1 even if the refund quantity is more than only 1.

Code bellow:

```
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'orders_list_preview_items', 20, 2 );
function orders_list_preview_items($column, $post_id) {
    
    global $the_order, $post;
    
    if ('order_status' === $column) {
        
        // Start list
        echo '<ul class="orders-list-items-preview">';
        
        // Loop through order items
        //if ($refunds){ 
        foreach($the_order->get_items() as $item) {
        
    //refunds
    //$qtyfin = 0;
    foreach ( $the_order->get_refunds() as $refund ) {
    foreach ( $refund->get_items() as $refunded_item ) {
        
    //if ( absint( $refunded_item->get_meta( '_refunded_item_id' ) ) === $refunded_item ) {
          $qtyfin = $refunded_item->get_quantity();
        //}
      }
    }
            
            $product = $item->get_product();
            $img     = wp_get_attachment_url($product->get_image_id());
            $name    = $item->get_name();
            $qty     = $item->get_quantity();
            
            $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
            $quantityfinal = $qty;

            if ($stock <= 0){
                $sklad = "Nie je skladom";
            } else {
                $sklad =  '<x style="color:green">Skladom: </x> <x class="valuestock">'.$stock.'ks</x>';
            }
            
            
            echo "<li>
                <img src=\"$img\" />
                <label>$quantityfinal</label> $name
                <label class='stock'>$sklad test: $qtyfin</label>
            </li>";
        }
    //}
        // End list
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    
    
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
...
// Loop through order items
//if ($refunds){ 
foreach($the_order->get_items() as $item_key => $item) {
    $qtyfin = $the_order->get_qty_refunded_for_item( $item_key );
    ...
```